# React app not rendering on home page after adding Header or Home component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Header from "./Header";
function App() {
return (

  <div className="app">
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/checkout">
          <h1>Checkout</h1>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">
          <h1>Login page</h1>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
        <Header/>
          <Home/>
          
          <h1>Home page</h1>
       </Route>
      </Switch>
      </Router>
      </div>
      
      
  );
}
export default App;
```

Header.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./Header.css";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import ShoppingBasketIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ShoppingBasket";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


function Header() {  
  return (
    <div className="header">
      
        <img className="header__logo" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/35/ca/74/35ca74aa0f5cbb599b83c02bf48499b5--design-logo-handicraft.jpg"/>
      

        
          <div className="header__optionBasket">
            <ShoppingBasketIcon />
            <span className="header__optionLineTwo header__basketCount">
              0
            </span>
          </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I tried to add Header and Home component in App.js and was expecting the stuffs which I added, but it is showing blank on the home page. In contrast, login page shows texts -"login". Where did I go wrong, I have been searching the same but cannot find any answer anywhere. My react router version is 5.2.0

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: oh sorry for that, I will do it

Comment: I don't see any overt issue with any of the routing code. Here's a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-app-not-rendering-on-home-page-after-adding-header-or-home-component-d3lpr3) of your code. Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: I see 2 opening div tags in Header.js and 3 closing div tags..?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with react-router, but It seems you are returning 3 components under 1 Route tag

So maybe put Header, Home and h1 in a div:

```
<Route>
 <div>
  <Header />
  <Home />
  <h1></h1>
 </div>
</Route>
```

Comment: it's still not working

Comment: Okay can you try to put only 1 component under it?

Comment: And if it works, try another component